# Jenkins - Cannot proceed with MSBuild

Tags: jenkins

I have worked almost one day with Jenkins to setup for automation publishing an ASP.NET web application. I have got it done in one local virtual machine, but it did not work when I tried with an production server.

Could any one can help or advise me? Here is the console error output:

```
......
no change for **SVNpath**1 since the previous build
Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe
Executing command: cmd.exe /C C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe /t:rebuild D:\JenkinsInstall\jobs\ADDevelopmentPublishing\workspace\Web\ABC\ABC.csproj && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe /t:rebuild D:\JenkinsInstall\jobs\ADDevelopmentPublishing\workspace\Web\ABC\ABC.csproj && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%

The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator.

Press any key to continue . . . 
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild.' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
------------------
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I'm so sorry of the format due to my first post. I will be more careful for next post.

Comment: Do you need to build on a production server? We run all our MS builds on one node and then push to various targets using [webdeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line:
 `The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator` indicates that you are not allowed to launch batch instructions on your server.

Comment: Thank your reply. But I also tried to resolve the message by logging to the server as administrator and then configure gpedit.msc utils to turn of the flag "Prevents users from running the interactive command prompt". After that Jenkins still did not work. (I installed Jenkins as a window service on my server)

Comment: @DavidNguyen (You didn't mention which version of Windows you are running on, so I hope this applies.)  As a service, Jenkins runs as "NT Authority\System".  You need to make sure that it has cmd prompt privileges.  You can test things by trying to run the cmd prompt as the system user.  This [answers how to run as the system user](http://serverfault.com/a/31415/73329).